Chashivut (importance) of Childrens' Torah
There are halachot about the ranking holiness of sefarim, e.g. what can go on top of what (בפרטי הקדושות זה למעלה מזה - Aruch Hashulchan 283:6).
What about the Torah of children? If my 4 year old writes a dvar Torah, or draws a purely Torah picture, e.g. a Sukkah, or even his "artists impression" of the yetzer hara etc. Can I put that on top of a sefer? Can I put something on top of it? What about my 6 year old? Or 9 year old?

With the obvious exception of avdei cochavim, apikorsim, and the like shouldn't the contents rather than the person who wrote them matter most?

Not necessarily an answer but the Rambam in hilchos Talmud Torah says a city that refuses to educate children should be destroyed and that the merit of the entire world comes from innocent children learning. In this regards one might say a davar Torah from a child has a greater importance than from an adult.

@Dude it's on the way to a great answer imo

@Dude Greater importance is not necessarily synonymous with greater kedusha.

What is the difference between the two here?

@Dude If you write a check to save a family, it's arguably more important than a chumash, but you wouldn't place it on top of a chumash.

That is a valid point but not specifically applicable since here we are comparing a davar Torah written by a child versus another davar Torah. Where in the realm of Torah do we find something that is more important but lesser kedusha?

No such halacha is ever mentioned in the halachos of kavod of seforim, so we can't make it up on our own.
It doesn't make sense to me either, because while a child's study of Torah is more holy and pure due to their lack of sin, the Torah itself is the same.

That's not how I understand these halachot - my general impression is that if a child produces a Torah work, it has less sanctity than a formal sefer, and it seems to me that you can probably put whatever you want on top of it, but that's just the Aruch Hashulchan. Thanks for taking the time, but this answer doesn't really bring anything useful to the table of this discussion.

What kind of source is general impression? My point is you didn't raise any issues that need a response besides a vague feeling. The Aruch Hashulchan basically says all seforim not written on klaf are equal.
